# Idempotent matrix and its fixed point set

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix $A \in M_n (\mathbb{R})$ , i.e, the set of $n \times n$ matrices whose entries are in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, I am asked to "show that the image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under $A$ is precisely the fixed-point set of $A$." Such a map is called a projection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto its image. Note: $A$ is idempotent

First of all, I'm not sure what is meant by the statement "image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under $A$", is it $\phi (\mathbb{R^n})$ when:

\begin{equation*}
\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n 
\end{equation*}

$\phi(x)= x A$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

If so, I couldn't show how $\phi(\mathbb{R}^n)$ becomes to fixed-point set of $A$. Furthermore, why would this map be called the "projection"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: From your title I assume that you want to assume that $A$ is an idempotent matrix. Can you tell the Jordan normal form of $A$ if $A$ is idempotent? Which eigenvalues will $A$ have? Can you relate this to fixed points of $A$?

Comment: @Bubaya Don't we mean $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi(x)=xA = x $ for fixed point sets? I guess so. Then eigenvectors of $A$ will be those fixed points right? by solving $x(A - I) = 0 $. I have no idea how to relate these to the fact that $A$ is idempotent.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda$. If $A^2x=Ax$, what can you tell about $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$Let $A$ be an idempotent matrix and choose a Jordan normal form $J$ such that $A=S^{-1}JS$. Since $A$ is idempotent, $A^2=(S^{-1}JS)^2=S^{-1}J^2S=S^{-1}JS=A$, so $J$ is also idempotent. Thus, $J$ does not have any off-diagonal entries, and the only eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $0$. In other words, $A$ is diagonalisable, and $\mathbf R^n=\operatorname{Eig}(A, 0)\oplus\operatorname{Eig}(A, 1)=\ker A\oplus\im A$, and $\im A=\operatorname{Eig}(A, 1)$ is the set of fixed points of $A$.

Then it is also clear why this is called a *projection*: The projection of a direct summand clearly is an idempotent map. Conversely, the above reasoning shows that *any* idempotent matrix is the projection onto its image.